# Deploy Office AddIn to SharePoint on-premises environment

Tags: sharepoint, office-js, office-addins

I am developing with Word Web AddIn by `Office.js`. Now I want to publish it to my `on-premises environment`.

After check [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish), it seems only [SharePoint catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog) supports **SharePoint on-premises**. But for this docuemnt, it shared the steps for `Sharepoint Online` instead of premises.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because we seem to have misunderstood each other. The second article that you link to has instructions for creating an add-in catalog in SharePoint on-premise and the very next section of the same article explains how to create one for SharePoint Online (Office 365). Please clarify your question to help us understand what information you need that isn't in that article.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for your help. I try to find the `Add-ins`  in the `Central Administration Site`, but I did not find it in SharePoint 2016 on-premise. Do you know any official docuemnt for sharepoint 2016 on-premise?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. It seems that when Microsoft renamed "apps for Office" and "apps for SharePoint" to "Office Add-ins" and "SharePoint Add-ins", the UI of SharePoint Central Administration was not changed. But whoever wrote that second article that you linked to thought that it had been changed. (Or maybe it was, but your SharePoint on-premise doesn't have an up-to-date build.) I think that when you get to step 2 of the article you linked to, you will find an "Apps" on the left side of the page instead of a "Add-ins". So just follow the directions in that article but in your mind replace "Add-in" with "App" in all the steps.

Another possibility is this article I found. Try using this, if the suggestion above doesn't work: [Manage the App Catalog in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-app-catalog).